# Forcing a query in Access to keep a "formula" in a field instead of a result

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following in one of the "Fields" of an Access query:

```
2BCT_P: IIf([2BCT_OH]=0,0,[2BCT_FMC]/[2BCT_OH])
```

Is it possible to make the false part

```
[2BCT_FMC]/[2BCT_OH]
```

of the IIf into something that will retain the formula when I paste the query results into Excel?

I know that I can do the following using VBA:
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1= "=R[0]C[1]"...

But if it were possible for me to write the query so that it retains appropriate "Formula" attribute, this would be desirable because then I wouldn't have to write a loop in VBA to paste these values.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you did:

```
2BCT_P: IIf([2BCT_OH]=0,0,"=[2BCT_FMC]/[2BCT_OH]")
```

you would just insert the text: '=[2BCT_FMC]/[2BCT_OH]

into the cell.

So you would have to use automation and open an instance of Excel and manipulate the cells of the worksheet this way.